# get wpautop to not wrap tags but only text

Tags: wp-autop

Is it possible for wpautop to only wrap plain text, so that e.g. here:

```
text

<a href="">link</a>
```

only the "text" gets wrapped. Why would you want to wrap tags anyway? Maybe anyone has a custom function?

Comment: Have you taken [a look at the source](http://queryposts.com/function/wpautop/), tried to figure out what it really does (hint: phpDocBlock) and tried to fix what you need yourself (which is a prerequisite)?

Comment: That would be the last straw of course. I cannot believe that i am the only one with this desire though, so i wanted to ask since i couldn't find any solution (that others have created) by myself.

Comment: Please read the doc block again. And please test this with no plugins activated and one of the default Twenty* themes in use.